# Странно отрабатывает axios

Tags: javascript, post, axios, vue3, state

Не пойму, в чем проблема. Использую Pinia (state менеджер для vue), написал там запрос на бэк на axios. В then пишу, что бы ответ от сервера помещался в переменную. Пытаюсь потом эту переменную вывести в консоль, возвращается пустая.

Пробовал и просто в функции переменную создавать, и в state помещать. Причем если помещать в
state, еще и ошибка возвращается, что переменная не найдена.

Прошу помочь более опытных коллег по цеху.

```js
export const useUserStore = defineStore("user", {
  state: () => {
    return {
      authKey: "",
      isAuth: false,
      login: "",
      password: "",
      passwordRepeat: "",
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      email: "",
      errorMessage: "",
      userData: {}
    }
  },
  actions: {
    createUser() {
      let userData = {};
      axios({
          method: "post",
          url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/create-user/",
          data: {
            "username": this.login,
            "email": this.email,
            "password": this.password,
            "first_name": this.firstName,
            "last_name": this.lastName
          }
        })
        .then(response => {
          userData = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error)
        })
      console.log(userData);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: console.log(userData); отрабатывает когда запрос ушел, а не когда он приходит. Небось если написать лог после userData = response.data; в then то там все будет. Подробнее о асинхронности https://doka.guide/js/async-in-js/

Comment: Отлично, но мне же нужно как то дальше с этим работать)
Кстати даже не подумал о том, что можно асинхронно же это написать. Спасибо)

Comment: Это и есть асинхронно

Comment: Ладно, спасибо)

Comment: вообще внутри  then должно быть только this.userData = response.data; Тогда все добавится в стору. Дополнительная let userData = {}; вообще ни к чему

Comment: Я это понимаю, это лишь ради теста было сделано. В целом я так и планировал, но мне в консоль возвращается ошибка, что this.userData не определена, что очень странно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать через async/await, но надо будет учесть, что createUser будет возвращать промис

```
actions: {
    async createUser() {
        const response = await axios({
            method: "post",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/create-user/",
            data: {
                "username": this.login,
                "email": this.email,
                "password": this.password,
                "first_name": this.firstName,
                "last_name": this.lastName
            }
        });
        const userData = response.data;
        console.log(userData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло